# how to put footnote in the table?

Tags: tables

I want to put footnote for AAAAAAAAA

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[font={normalsize}]{caption}
\usepackage[para,flushleft]{threeparttable}
\renewcommand{\TPTtagStyle}{\textit}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{rotating}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\linespread{1}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

% packages for tables
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{fullpage} 
\usepackage[skip=1ex, 
            font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
% packages for tables
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx, varwidth}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Grid search leaderboard}
\begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
\hline
 Test No.& type&SeASDues & $R^2$ & PrAcessing& ML moADls& MeSDFaASFdel \\ \hline
1 & Stacked  & 12 & 0.96 & PCA & PolyFASres, EADR, DTR, GSDFR & LassoLarsCV\\
2 & Stacked &  14 & 0ASD3& ZeroSDnt, MinMaSDFDaler& DT, ETR, RiSFe&XGB\\
3 & Stacked &  17 & 0.96 &  ZeroCASDunt,RobASDScaler&RiSDgeCV&XBG\\
\textbf{4} & \textbf{Stacked} & \textbf{18}& \textbf{0SDF8}& \textbf{MinMADScaler, RobustScaler}& \textbf{GBR, PolyFeADres, LassoLarsCV} & \textbf{RSFgeCV} \\
\textbf{5} &  \textbf{Stacked} & \ASDA& \ASDASD9 & \textbf{TTT} & \textbf{GBR, PSDFADes, SGD, DTR} & \textbf{LassoLarsCV}\\
6 & Stacked &20 & 0SDF5 &-& RF,  AAAAAAAAAA    , PolyFeatSDFres  &LassoLarsCV\\
7 & Stacked & 75 & 0.SD6 & -&F\_regression, XGB & XGB\\
 8& Stacked & 100 & 0.95 &ZeroCount, RobustScaler, MaxAbsScaler & XGB, Ridge & GBR\\
\textbf{9} &  \textbf{ANN} & \textbf{12}&\textbf{0.80} &\textbf{MinMaxScaler} &\textbf{[13,32,32,1]}  &\textbf{-}\\
10 &ANN &16  & 0.53 & MinMaxScaler  & [13,512,128,1]& - \\
 11& ANN & 22 & 0.71 &MinMaxScaler& [13,64,512,1] &-\\
 12& ANN & 100 & 0.77 & MinMaxScaler & [13,128,1024,16,1] &-\\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Whatever else you do, please don’t use `\resizebox`.

Comment: For example, by use of the `threeparttable` or `talltblr˙ of `tabularray` package. And as @Mico said, don't scale table. Also please extend your code fragment to complete small document.

Comment: so how can I scale table it goes outside of page? while using three table.

Comment: Simple. Make table narrower. To help you, please extend your code fragment to complete document (MWE) with table. Page layout has strong influence to table design.

Comment: Sorry did not get it? you mean change code and put again? I put begin end also. resize yes did not work with footnote

Comment: Which documentclass you use? Your edit still not provide MWE ...

Comment: Aha. now ok thanks

Comment: Have a look at [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options)

Comment: @AhmadTurani, your MWE is still not complete. Missed are package `floats` as well your definitions or you have errors in code. So far it is not compilable. Please test it before publish here.

Comment: as far as i see it is working

Comment: Unfortunately no. Where are defined `\ASDA`, \ASDASD9`?

Comment: I put in overleaf and it worked without error!

Answer (score 3):

To long for the comment ...

- Your document example unfortunately doesn't work. It also afzer your edits still use some undefined commands.
- It not contain any footnote. Please add it where you like to have `\footnotemark`
- Do you really need all those packages? Some of them are already loaded by other packages, some are loaded twice ... Cleanup your preamble!
- Package `hyperref` should be loaded last.

For starting point you may for table `xtabularx` use and define forth and fifth column as `L` type, for which in preamble define `\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}`:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Grid search leaderboard}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\small
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} cccl LL l @{}}
\hline
\makecell{Test\\ No.} & type & \makecell{SeAS\\Dues} & $R^2$ & PrAcessing& ML moADls& \makecell{MeSD-\\ FaASFdel} \\ \hline
```

By this changes, your table will fit in text block:

[image]

For inserting footnotes, Please first edit your question again with considering aforementioned. Then We will be able simple add desired footnote.

Comment: Thank you so much. there is "AAAAAAAAAA" in the middle which I want to add footnote for it. I will dit and let you know. By the way small makes font smaller?

Comment: @AhmadTurani, well, you know where you like to have `\footnotemark`, just add `˙\footnote` there. Yes, the command `\small` make font smaller. I suggest you to read some introductory text about LateX. For example https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Since your code loads the `threeparttable` package, you might as well make use of it to generate the desired footnote. Please see the code below for an example of how to employ `\tnote` directives and the `tablenotes` environment.

To make the table fit inside the width of the text block, I suggest you employ a `tabularx` environment and employ the `X` column type for columns 5 and 6.

[image]

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{geometry}
%%\usepackage{epsfig}
%%\usepackage{latexsym} % latexsym was superseded by amssymb in 1994
\usepackage{amssymb}
%%\usepackage[font=normalsize]{caption}

\usepackage[para,flushleft]{threeparttable}
\renewcommand{\TPTtagStyle}{\textit}

\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
%%\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\captionsetup{skip=1ex, font=small, labelfont=bf} % are you sure about "font=small"?
\usepackage{rotating}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\linespread{1}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

% packages for tables
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%%%\usepackage{graphics}
%%%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{color,soul}
%%\usepackage{fullpage}

% packages for tables
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow} %%%, tabularx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx, varwidth}
%%\usepackage{tablefootnote}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lineno}  %%,hyperref}
\modulolinenumbers[5]

%% new code:
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2} % seems excessive
\begin{table}[ht]
%%\centering % not needed
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Grid search leaderboard}
\label{GridASDASDh}
% Allow automatic line breaks in columns 5 and 6:
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l ccc LL l @{}}
\toprule %\hline
 Test No.& type & SeASDues & $R^2$ & PrAcessing & ML moADls & MeSDFaASFdel \\
\midrule %\hline
1 & Stacked & 12 & 0.96 & PCA & PolyFASres, EADR, DTR, GSDFR & LassoLarsCV\\
\addlinespace
2 & Stacked & 14 & 0ASD3& ZeroSDnt, MinMaSDFDaler& DT, ETR, RiSFe&XGB\\
\addlinespace
3 & Stacked & 17 & 0.96 &  ZeroCASDunt, RobASDScaler & RiSDgeCV & XBG\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{4} & \textbf{Stacked} & \textbf{18} & \textbf{0SDF8} & \textbf{MinMADScaler, RobustScaler}& \textbf{GBR, PolyFeADres, LassoLarsCV} & \textbf{RSFgeCV} \\
\addlinespace
\textbf{5} & \textbf{Stacked} & ASDA & ASDASD9 & \textbf{TTT} & \textbf{GBR, PSDFADes, SGD, DTR} & \textbf{LassoLarsCV}\\
\addlinespace
6 & Stacked & 20 & 0SDF5 & -- & RF, AAAAAAAAAA,\tnote{a} PolyFeatSDFres  &LassoLarsCV\\
\addlinespace
7 & Stacked & 75 & 0.SD6 & -- & F\_regression, XGB & XGB\\
\addlinespace
8 & Stacked & 100& 0.95 & ZeroCount, RobustScaler, MaxAbsScaler & XGB, Ridge & GBR\\
\addlinespace
\textbf{9} & \textbf{ANN} & \textbf{12} & \textbf{0.80}     & \textbf{MinMaxScaler} & \textbf{[13,32,32,1]} & \textbf{--}\\
\addlinespace
10& ANN     & 16 & 0.53 & MinMaxScaler & [13,512,128,1]     & -- \\
\addlinespace
11& ANN     & 22 & 0.71 & MinMaxScaler & [13,64,512,1]      & -- \\
\addlinespace
12& ANN     & 100& 0.77 & MinMaxScaler & [13,128,1024,16,1] & -- \\
\bottomrule %\hline
\end{tabularx}

\smallskip\footnotesize
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a] Some footnote text.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{table}

\lipsum[1-5] % filler text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mico. there is many sentences added i dont know where they come from !! Nulla malesuada porttitor diam. Donec felis erat, congue non, volutpat at, tincidunt tristique, libero.
Vivamus viverra fermentum felis. Donec nonummy pellentesque ante. Phasellus adipiscing semper elit. Proin
fermentum massa ac quam. Sed diam turpis, molestie vitae, placerat a, molestie nec, leo. Maecenas lacinia.
Nam ipsum ligula, eleifend at, accumsan nec, suscipit a, ipsum. Morbi blandit ligula feugiat magna. Nunc
eleifend consequat lorem. Sed lacinia nulla vitae enim. Pellentesque tincidunt purus vel

Comment: @AhmadTurani - That's strictly optional filler text, generated by the directive `\lipsum[1-5]`. The main purpose of the filler text is to illustrate the width of the text block. In your own code, you should obviously not include `\lipsum` directives.

Comment: Thank you. unfortunately due to my other packages I think my table is not consistent like yours

Comment: @AhmadTurani - Not sure what to say. The code I provided employs the same document class and loads the same packages as you say your code does.